# OTP Issue on TWITTER DIGITS for VOLTE Only Carrier

Tags: android

While doing OTP verification via Twiiter Digits, if the user is on VOLTE only connection and WIFI is connected on phone then DIGITS does not send OTP SMS. How can this be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possible solution could be to check whether the user is on a Packet only (PS) carrier  and if the WIFI is connected then show a Alert to the User to turn OFF WIFI.

You can use the following code for this:-

```
private void check_wifi_for_volte(){
        TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String carrierName = manager.getNetworkOperatorName();
        Log.d(TAG,"carrierName:"+carrierName);

        boolean isWifiActive =false;
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (activeNetwork != null) { // connected to the internet
            if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                // connected to wifi
                isWifiActive=true;
                //Toast.makeText(this, activeNetwork.getTypeName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                // connected to the mobile provider's data plan
                //Toast.makeText(this, activeNetwork.getTypeName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            // not connected to the internet
           // can we show some toast not connected to internet
        }

        boolean isPSUser = carrierName.toLowerCase().contains(<PS-CARRIER>);

        if(isPSUser && isWifiActive){
            Toast.makeText(this, "If you are using PS Network. Turn OFF WIFI to get OTP SMS.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```